# Paged query on entity with calculated field

Tags: java, pagination, ebean, mssql-jdbc

I have a paged query on a view where one of the fields is anottated with `@Formula` (Using ajahe ebean query).

When running the query on a `page > 0` I get an error:

> PersistenceException: Query threw SQLException:No column name was specified for column 8 of 'limitresult'.

The generated query is:

```
select * 
from ( 
  select top 20 row_number() over (order by product_id) as rn, 
    t0.product_id c0, t0.isbn c1, 
    t0.provider_external_id c2, 
    t0.total_inventory c3, 
    t0.total_fulfilled c4, 
    t0.total_not_for_sale c5, 
    total_inventory - total_fulfilled - total_not_for_sale
  from product_stock_status t0 
  order by product_id 
) 
as limitresult where rn > 10 and rn <= 20 .
```

Running this query directly on the database (mssql) results in the same exception.

Adding alias to the generated value `total_inventory - total_fulfilled - total_not_for_sale` solves the problem, however I don't know how to get the framework to add an alias to get the query to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add an alias to the formula definition:
instead of
@Formula(select = "total_inventory - total_fulfilled - total_not_for_sale")

Changed to
@Formula(select = "total_inventory - total_fulfilled - total_not_for_sale as totalAvailable")